# Firestore Security Rule for arrayContains Query

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a dynamic query for a basic search functionality that uses arrayContains to show results;

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('colName')
.where('arrayFieldName', arrayContains: 'somestring')
.snapshots'
```

Is it possible to set up a Firestore Security Rule that checks if the string ('somestring') used in arrayContains has at least 3 characters?

*Thank you,*

Comment: The query on client-side starts if textField has 3 characters. (like any basic search field would do) But i'd like to know if we can limit querying the whole collection with such a rule.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.  You can't access the value of that string or put constraints on its value.  If you want the elements of the `arrayFieldName` array property to contain at least three characters, that's something you'll have to enforce at the time the value is *written*, not at the time that it's *queried*.

Comment: I'm using array field to index the keyword. Like;
0. k
1. ke
2. key
3. keyw
4. keywo
5. keywor
6. keyword

I guess you got the idea. On client side the search query starts when 3rd character is entered. That works quite qood. So with your answer, the only choice for me is to check for query limit value, right? I need to limit the count of returned documents. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It sounds like you have to check that on the client app, not security rules.  The app will need code to perform the query only after enough characters have been entered by the user.

Comment: I've found a similar situation; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961574/firestore-security-rules-based-on-request-query-value

Comment: Nothing in that answer is going to help you in this case, however.